# Minimizer of Kullback-Leibler divergence of non-symmetric distributions

Tags: model-selection, convergence, kullback-leibler

I am working on a convergence result for an economics paper but am struggling with the following:

Suppose you have two distributions, $f(a)$ and $g(a)$ of the same non-symmetric family. Suppose that *at least* one of the two distributions' moments differs between the two.

The Kullback-Leibler divergence between the two distributions is defined as
$$
D(f\Vert g)=\int_{a\in\mathbb{R}}f(a)\log \frac{f(a)}{g(a)}da.
$$

Suppose you want to set the mean of distribution $g(a)$ such that it minimizes the above KL divergence.

**Is it generally true that we minimize the KL divergence by setting the mean of $g(a)$ equal to that of $f(a)$---i.e., $\mathbb{E}[g(a)]=\mathbb{E}[f(a)]$?**

My intuition tells me that this would be true were the distributions symmetric. I do not think, however, that it is true for the case described here where the distributions are asymmetric. I can't find a proof of this (although I am sure one must exist somewhere), nor do I quite know how I would go about proving this myself.

Any advice and hints are greatly appreciated!